# Unable to Connect Microsoft SQL Server to Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am facing this issue:

I am Using SpringBoot Application and have 2  Data Sources one is MySQl and second Microsoft SQL Server

Using JPA

This Database is present in some Remote Server/Machine.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'secondEntityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/my/in/config/SecondDBConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1794) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1109) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) [spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) [spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.my.in.MyApplication.main(MyApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:403) ~[spring-orm-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378) ~[spring-orm-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1790) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getLong(SQLServerResultSet.java:2151) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getLong(HikariProxyResultSet.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.resultSetStartValueSize(SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.java:129) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.extractMetadata(SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.java:59) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.initializeSequences(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:65) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.<init>(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:59) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.buildDatabaseInformation(Helper.java:155) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:96) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:184) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:316) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:469) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1259) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

Comment: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long this is the Main reason

Comment: Can you post the code inside your org/my/in/config/SecondDBConfig.java ? I think you are trying to read some long value from some config file and its getting parsed as 'int'. Try appending 'L' (123L) to that value and see if it works.

Comment: try to use (Integer) row.get("id")).longValue() for integer field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known bug in hubernate](https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/java-lang-classcastexception-java-math-cannot-be-cast-to-java-lang-long-while-starting-server/4074/5)

The solution they found was to create a custom dialect (oddly enough...)

```
package ....;

import org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect;
import org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorNoOpImpl;
import org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.spi.SequenceInformationExtractor;
/**
 * Custom SQLServer dialect to deal with SEQUENCE schema query result processing issue
 */
public class SQLServerCustomDialect extends SQLServer2012Dialect {

  @Override
  public SequenceInformationExtractor getSequenceInformationExtractor() {
    if ( getQuerySequencesString() == null ) {
      return SequenceInformationExtractorNoOpImpl.INSTANCE;
    }
    else {
      return SequenceInformationExtractorImpl.INSTANCE;
    }
  }

}
```

With a slightly awkward adapter class to properly convert the value between int and long

```
/*
 * Hibernate, Relational Persistence for Idiomatic Java
 *
 * License: GNU Lesser General Public License (LGPL), version 2.1 or later.
 * See the lgpl.txt file in the root directory or <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-2.1.html>.
 *
 * Adapted from the class with the same name in the Hibernate distribution.
 */

package ...;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.QualifiedSequenceName;
import org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.IdentifierHelper;
import org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorNoOpImpl;
import org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationImpl;
import org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.spi.ExtractionContext;
import org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.spi.SequenceInformation;
import org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.spi.SequenceInformationExtractor;

/**
 * @author Steve Ebersole
 */
public class SequenceInformationExtractorImpl implements SequenceInformationExtractor {
  /**
   * Singleton access
   */
  public static final SequenceInformationExtractorImpl INSTANCE = new SequenceInformationExtractorImpl();

  @Override
  public Iterable<SequenceInformation> extractMetadata(final ExtractionContext extractionContext) throws SQLException {
    final String lookupSql = extractionContext.getJdbcEnvironment().getDialect().getQuerySequencesString();

    // *should* never happen, but to be safe in the interest of performance...
    if ( lookupSql == null ) {
      return SequenceInformationExtractorNoOpImpl.INSTANCE.extractMetadata( extractionContext );
    }

    final IdentifierHelper identifierHelper = extractionContext.getJdbcEnvironment().getIdentifierHelper();
    final Statement statement = extractionContext.getJdbcConnection().createStatement();
    try {
      final ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery( lookupSql );
      try {
        final List<SequenceInformation> sequenceInformationList = new ArrayList<>();
        while ( resultSet.next() ) {
          sequenceInformationList.add(
              new SequenceInformationImpl(
                  new QualifiedSequenceName(
                      identifierHelper.toIdentifier(
                        resultSetCatalogName( resultSet )
                      ),
                      identifierHelper.toIdentifier(
                          resultSetSchemaName( resultSet )
                      ),
                      identifierHelper.toIdentifier(
                          resultSetSequenceName( resultSet )
                      )
                  ),
                  resultSetStartValueSize( resultSet ),
                  resultSetMinValue( resultSet ),
                  resultSetMaxValue( resultSet ),
                  resultSetIncrementValue( resultSet )
              )
          );
        }
        return sequenceInformationList;
      }
      finally {
        try {
          resultSet.close();
        }
        catch (final SQLException ignore) {
        }
      }
    }
    finally {
      try {
        statement.close();
      }
      catch (final SQLException ignore) {
      }
    }
  }

  protected String sequenceNameColumn() {
    return "sequence_name";
  }

  protected String sequenceCatalogColumn() {
    return "sequence_catalog";
  }

  protected String sequenceSchemaColumn() {
    return "sequence_schema";
  }

  protected String sequenceStartValueColumn() {
    return "start_value";
  }

  protected String sequenceMinValueColumn() {
    return "minimum_value";
  }

  protected String sequenceMaxValueColumn() {
    return "maximum_value";
  }

  protected String sequenceIncrementColumn() {
    return "increment";
  }

  protected String resultSetSequenceName(final ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
    return resultSet.getString( sequenceNameColumn() );
  }

  protected String resultSetCatalogName(final ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
    final String column = sequenceCatalogColumn();
    return column != null ? resultSet.getString( column ) : null;
  }

  protected String resultSetSchemaName(final ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
    final String column = sequenceSchemaColumn();
    return column != null ? resultSet.getString( column ) : null;
  }

  protected Long resultSetStartValueSize(final ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
    final String column = sequenceStartValueColumn();
    return column != null ? resultSetGetAsLong( resultSet, column ) : null;
  }

  protected Long resultSetMinValue(final ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
    final String column = sequenceMinValueColumn();
    return column != null ? resultSetGetAsLong( resultSet, column ) : null;
  }

  protected Long resultSetMaxValue(final ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
    final String column = sequenceMaxValueColumn();
    return column != null ? resultSetGetAsLong( resultSet, column ) : null;
  }

  protected Long resultSetIncrementValue(final ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
    final String column = sequenceIncrementColumn();
    return column != null ? resultSetGetAsLong( resultSet, column ) : null;
  }

  private Long resultSetGetAsLong(final ResultSet resultSet, final String column) throws SQLException {
    final Object value = resultSet.getObject(column);
    if (value == null || !(value instanceof Number)) {
      return null;
    }
    return ((Number)value).longValue();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank You for your Response.....I followed the steps mentioned by you,and it Worked